# Why does Go use more CPUs but does not reduce computing duration?

Tags: go, parallel-processing

I wrote a simple Go program to add numbers in many goroutines.
When I increase number of goroutines, the program uses more CPUs and I expect the computing duration is shorter. It is true for 1, 2 or 4 goroutines, but when I try 8 goroutines, the duration is the same as 4 (I run the test on i5-8265U, a 8 CPUs processor).
Can you explain it to me?
The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// Sum returns n by calculating 1+1+1+..
func Sum(n int64) int64 {
    ret := int64(0)
    for i := int64(0); i < n; i++ {
        ret += 1
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    n := int64(30000000000) // 30e9
    sum := int64(0)
    beginTime := time.Now()

    nWorkers := 4
    sumChan := make(chan int64, nWorkers)
    for i := 0; i < nWorkers; i++ {
        go func() { sumChan <- Sum(n / int64(nWorkers)) }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < nWorkers; i++ {
        sum += <-sumChan
    }

    fmt.Println("dur:", time.Since(beginTime))
    fmt.Println("sum:", sum)

    // Results on Intel Core i5-8265U (nWorkers,dur):
    // (1, 8s), (2, 4s), (4, 2s), (8, 2s). Why 8 CPUs still need 2s?
}
```

Comment: What does this return? https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS

Comment: @vll It returns 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I run the test on i5-8265U, a 8 CPUs processor

[The i5-8265U is not an 8-core CPU, it's a 4-core 8-threads CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149088/intel-core-i5-8265u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html): it has 4 physical cores, and each core can run 2 threads *concurrently* via [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

The "performance advantage" of HT depends on the workloads, and the ability to "mix in" operations from one thread with the computations of another. This means if your CPU is highly loaded, the hyper-threads may not be able to get more than a few % of the runtime, and thus not contribute much to the total performances.

Furthermore, the 8265U has a nominal frequency of 1.6GHz and a maximum turbo of 3.9 (3.7 on 4 cores). It's also possible that fully loading the CPU including hyperthreads would further lower the "turbo ceiling". You'd have to [check the cpuinfo state](https://pzemtsov.github.io/2016/12/08/turbo-boost-and-performance.html) during the run to see.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know more about "logical cores"